# Two way bindings in component not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm new in Angular, I'm currently developping a little project. I followed tutorials on two-way bindings and I'm now trying to do it in my project. I have a component but when I try to set values in the html, it does not work. As I'm very new to this, it certainly is a stupid mistake but I can't figure out what it is.

When I use one way-binding it work (with [] only) but when I add () to the html tags, it does not work anymore.

Here is my html code from my custom component:

```
<form class="form_MyProfil">
  <table class="myprofil_width" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <mat-form-field class="myprofil_width">
          <input matInput [(ngModel)]="ngName" name="username" placeholder="Username"  disabled>
        </mat-form-field>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <mat-form-field class="myprofil_width">
          <input matInput [(ngModel)]="ngPassword" name="password" placeholder="New password" [type]="hide ? 'password' : 'text'">
          <mat-icon matSuffix (click)="hide = !hide">{{hide ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}</mat-icon>
        </mat-form-field>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <mat-form-field class="myprofil_width">
          <input matInput [(ngModel)]="ngMail" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" required>
        </mat-form-field>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <mat-form-field class="myprofil_width">
          <input matInput [(ngModel)]="ngTown" name="town" placeholder="Town"  type="text" required>
        </mat-form-field>
      </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </form>
```

And here is my ts code from the same component :

```
 @Component({
 selector: 'app-my-profil',
 templateUrl: './my-profil.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./my-profil.component.css']
 } )
 export class MyProfilComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
 ngOnInit(): void {
 this.loadProfil();
 }
 username:string;
 password:string;
 email:string;
 town:string;


 private userProfil: UserRegister;
 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private router: Router,
 private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
 private repo: RepositoryService,
 private alertService: AlertService) { }




//Load the profil of the user and assign the values to the form
 loadProfil(): void {
 this.repo.getData('api/Profil')
   .subscribe((res: UserRegister) => {
     this.userProfil = res;
     this.username = this.userProfil.userName;
     this.town = this.userProfil.town;
     this.fiability = this.userProfil.fiability;
     this.email = this.userProfil.email;
     this.nbEvents = 'Went to :' + 
     this.userProfil.nbEventsParticipated.toString() + '/' + 
     this.userProfil.nbEventRegistered.toString() + ' Events';
   },
     error => {
       this.alertService.error(error);
     });
   }
```

The method loadProfil make an API call that send the data correctly but when I try to set the values, it does not work.

If someone can see why, an answer would be very appreciated.

Have a good day,

Lio

Comment: you have not defined ``ngName`` , ``ngPassword `` and hence it will not work

Comment: PS : I use Angular Material, and FormsModule has been correctly imported

Comment: Why do you use `ngName`, `ngPassword`, `ngMail`, `ngTown` in the template? It should be `username`, `password`, `email`, `town`. For example: `[(ngModel)]="email"`.

Comment: Should I defined ngName or username ? I'm a bit confused about that

Comment: The name and the ngModel have to be the same "name"? Like [(ngModel)]="username name="username"?

Comment: ``ngModel`` bind the value to the defined variable ``ngName`` which is not defined in your ``.ts`` file . use ``[(ngModel)]=username`` and it will work.

Comment: Not necessarily the same as the name attribute; but rather the same as the property in `MyProfilComponent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Should fill the name and ngModel with same name of model that exist in ts file:

```
<form class="form_MyProfil">
  <table class="myprofil_width" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <mat-form-field class="myprofil_width">
          <input matInput [(ngModel)]="username" name="username" placeholder="Username"  disabled>
        </mat-form-field>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <mat-form-field class="myprofil_width">
          <input matInput [(ngModel)]="password" name="password" placeholder="New password" [type]="hide ? 'password' : 'text'">
          <mat-icon matSuffix (click)="hide = !hide">{{hide ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}</mat-icon>
        </mat-form-field>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <mat-form-field class="myprofil_width">
          <input matInput [(ngModel)]="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" required>
        </mat-form-field>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <mat-form-field class="myprofil_width">
          <input matInput [(ngModel)]="town" name="town" placeholder="Town"  type="text" required>
        </mat-form-field>
      </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </form>
```